# Add an isoquant curve to a scatterplot made in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was curious if anyone knew how to create a heatmap with an isoquant curve that identifies all x and y combinations whose product equals a certain constant. The final product should look like the following picture:

[Scatterplot with isoquant curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TAmQ.png)

Here is the code I use to generate my plot, but as of right now I can't get the curve in the plot as depicted in the picture above:

```
vs.vpd.by.drop_days <- ggplot(event_drops, aes(vs, vpd)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = day_since), size = 2, alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("darkblue","green","yellow","red"),
                        breaks = c(0,25,50,75),
                        limits = c(0,75),
                        name = "Days since \n first drop") +
  ggtitle("Drops by VPD and Wind Speed") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 15)) +
  xlab(label = "Wind Speed (mph)") +
  ylab(label = "Vapor Pressure Deficit") +
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,20)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,5)) 

vs.vpd.by.drop_days
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve that would be `geom_function`.

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) 3000 / x)
```

[image]

Comment: Second question, do you know how I would add a separate legend denoting the isoquant line?

Comment: Sure. You get an legend if you map on an aesthetic, e.g. you could do `geom_function(aes(linetype = "Iso"), fun = function(x) 3000 / x)` to add a linetype legend.